Using a raster when it is 'the output is a list of SpatRaster objects'
I am trying to make a set of rasters/maps with pixel level heterogeneity calculations using the R package 'rasterdiv'. I'd then like to look at the resulting maps in QGIS, presumably meaning I'd need to write them as GeoTiffs using a 'writeRaster' function. However, the output for some of these functions is not a SpatRaster, but 'a list of SpatRaster objects'.
For example, using the paRao function and example on its webpage:   https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rasterdiv/versions/0.3.4/topics/paRao
data(volcano)
r <- terra::rast(volcano)

res <- paRao(x = r, window = 3, alpha = 2, method = "classic")
terra::plot(res[[1]][[1]])

Here the resulting 'res' is a list of 1, of which I have not been able to write to a GeoTiff. How can I access this raster?

It looks like the returned value is a list because you can specify multiple window and alpha values and get results from all combinations, so its a nested list structure even if there's only one value of each.
For example:
library(terra)
res <- paRao(x = r, window = c(3,5), alpha = c(2,3), method = "classic")
[lots of stuff happens]

Giving an object with a nested list structure:
str(res)
List of 2
 $ window.3:List of 2
  ..$ alpha.2:S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]
  ..$ alpha.3:S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]
 $ window.5:List of 2
  ..$ alpha.2:S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]
  ..$ alpha.3:S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]

You can then pick out each of these by name or by index. Going back to your single value and single returned raster example you'd do:
writeRaster(res[[1]][[1]],"/tmp/r1.tiff")

or
writeRaster(res$window.3$alpha.2,"/tmp/r1.tiff")

If you have got multiple rasters in a nested list from running that function:
> res <- paRao(x = r, window = c(3,5), alpha = c(2,3), method = "classic")
> str(res)
List of 2
 $ window.3:List of 2
  ..$ alpha.2:S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]
  ..$ alpha.3:S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]
 $ window.5:List of 2
  ..$ alpha.2:S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]
  ..$ alpha.3:S4 class 'SpatRaster' [package "terra"]

you can unlist it and create a multi-band raster which you can then write as a single multi-band TIFF:
> resm = rast(unlist(res))
> resm
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 87, 61, 4  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
[...]
> writeRaster(resm, "/tmp/resm.tiff")


There is a package function "process_raster_result" in rasterdiv that handles naming and formatting, into a single SpatRaster, of the nested list output.
